# Is there video codec pack for Quick time player?

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

There are several video players for OS X, VLC and MplayerX are most popular. But VLC allow to open only 1 window, and MplayerX has adware. 
Is there a codec pack or any way to install codecs into the system, to open most popular video formats like avi, mkv etc. with native Quick time player?

Comment: There used to be [Perian](https://www.perian.org), but it's no longer supported

Comment: Yes, i know, and that's the problem. Perian, a i know, doesn't work on El Cap. So i'm looking for another solution.

Comment: You can have [multiple](http://superuser.com/questions/894840/how-to-play-multiple-instances-of-vlc-on-mac) VLC's running

Comment: The thing is that AVKit/AVFoundation (which has replaced QTKit/Quicktime) may perhaps support codec plugins but it’s still not documented anywhere, so there’s no solution at the moment, see [relevant Perian issue](https://github.com/MaddTheSane/perian/issues/3).